# Defining PHP Constants - What Is My Server Name?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have:

```
<?php define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost')
```

If I put this constants.php file on my web host's server, is it still 'localhost'? Or something else.

I use hostmonster.com for my website. Does that replace localhost?

Comment: You want to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` as the value of the define.

Comment: And what is the 'server_name'? That is what I don't know...

Comment: See the [$_SERVER](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) documentation on php.net.

Comment: It literally is `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, it will look up the servers name. You may still want to use localhost if the db is on the same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should still use 'localhost' to connect to the database server.

Have a look at the hostmonitor help, 'Using the database'.

https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/6

Using the Database

> After doing all these steps, create the database's tables either via
>   phpMyAdmin, MySQL software or use an online PHP or Perl script.
>
> ```
> Version: MySQL 5
> Username: username_dbuser
> Database Name: username_dbname
> Hostaddress: localhost
> Port: 3306
> ```

Obviously, use your own database username and database name :)
(The ones you got when creating the database)

Comment: Would I have to create a user first to have a database username/pass? Or am I using my login credentials for my PHPMyAdmin?

The only reason I ask is because when you create a database there are no users associated to it. Do you mean I need to make a user for it first?

Comment: Your phpmyadmin user/password *should* work fine - give it a go and let us know whether that worked or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a string. A simple, hardcoded string. It won't magically change, because it's not a variable. `'localhost'` will always be `'localhost'`.

Comment: so I don't put..

<?php define('DB_SERVER', 'hostmonster.com')  ??

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: localhost points to a localhost set up on my computer, right? So does it need to change when I upload it to my web host's server??

Comment: localhost is the machine that the script runs on. Whether that's the correct value or not depends on what you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You define here a PHP constant, not a value that comes from server's headers (localhost)